# How can I read Yaml files?

Tags: 8

I have been trying to figure out how to decode ( also try to encode) my YML file so I can have full control over on PHP array. I try this...

[image]

And as you can see, I did not get the information inside of the YML file.

My question is what I'm doing wrong ? Why is not showing me the information inside of `/core/modules/toolbar/toolbar.breakpoints.yml` file?

Here is code snippet...

```
use Drupal\Component\Serialization\Yaml;

$breakpointEncoded = Yaml::encode('/core/modules/toolbar/toolbar.breakpoints.yml');
var_dump($breakpointEncoded);
```

Comment: Hi Darol - I think that function needs actual YAML, so you'd have to read the file in first. That said, I think there is a core service that can do both.

Comment: I think there's only https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/serialization.yaml/8.2.x @cilefen, which proxies straight through to the same class. I don't think there's a core method that will also load the file contents for you

Comment: "think" as in, "I think I saw that at a sprint three years ago", so goes the memory...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The arg to [`decode`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Serialization%21Yaml.php/function/Yaml%3A%3Adecode/8.2.x) is:

> The raw data string to decode

So you need (e.g.):

```
$breakpointEncoded = Yaml::decode(file_get_contents('/PATH/TO/core/modules/toolbar/toolbar.breakpoints.yml'));
```

Comment: I haven't really been digging through the Yaml class, but what happens if `file_get_contents()` returns `FALSE` i.e. if the path is wrong or not readable? Wouldn't that trigger an exception quite easily? :) What about storing the result of `file_get_contents()` and checking it for false before calling `Yaml::decode()` might help others avoid possible crashes.

Comment: Absolutely @hampusn - this is just a very basic sample snippet, I'll leave integrating around business logic/exception handling to the user :)

Comment: Fair point @Clive! I'm just hoping no copy/pasters take this to production :D

Comment: They've got to learn @hampusn ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Symfony component as well in Drupal 8:

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;    

$file_path = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/core/modules/toolbar/toolbar.breakpoints.yml';
$file_contents = file_get_contents($file_path);
$ymldata = Yaml::parse($file_contents);
```

Comment: Since Drupal 8.4 (using symphony 3.0) Yaml::Parse no longer takes a file name, so only the second variant works.

Comment: Thanks, I have removed the first variant where it passed in a file name.

Answer (score 1):

Even simplier now with a one-liner on Drupal 8.9 (the `decode` function has been removed from the Yaml Symfony Dependency utility class) :

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml; 

$ymldata = Yaml::parseFile(DRUPAL_ROOT . '/core/modules/toolbar/toolbar.breakpoints.yml');
```

Comment: You really need to specify WHICH Yaml class you're talking about. When you mention "Drupal 8.9" it sounds like you're talking about the Drupal Yaml class and that you're telling us about a change that was made in Drupal since the previous answers. That's not true. The Drupal Yaml class did not remove decode(), and does not have a parseFile() method. You must be talking about the Symfony class then - please add the appropriate "use" statement to your answer.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I edit the answer.